# 'I find it surprising seeing so many people here.'?

Tags: usage

This is an example sentence from Cambridge Dictionary.

> *I find it surprising to see so many people here.*

What I want to know is whether ***to see*** can be replaced with ***seeing***.

> *I find it surprising **seeing** so many people here.*

Comment: Are you asking about **to see|seeing**  as a complement to **surprising** in particular?Or  do you want to know about *find it ... aggravating, disheartening, offf-putting, amusing*, etc etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to say this, it would sound very natural. If your concern is correctness of the sentence you could alternatively say.

> I find it surprising that I'm seeing so many people here.